# Textview wrapping in Android

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

I have to display the `Textview` in Android getting from `xml` feed.

Let us take this is my `Textview`:

```
Mallika Sherawat's upcoming movie Dirty Politics
```

Here I have created the layout dynamically for these `Textview`:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
textLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setSingleLine(false);
tv.setEllipsize(null);
tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a7a9ac"));
tv.setText(Appscontent.Sub_arraylisttwo.get(j));
tv.setLayoutParams(textLayoutParams);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#414042"));
```

I have mentioned the width 50 here.

So the text is displayed well on small content `Textview`.some time I have more content `Textview` which means how can I display the `Textview` like below:

```
Mallika Sherawat's 
upcoming movie Dirty...
```

I mean the text is have to display maximum 2 lines only after the text is extended means simply add the `...` content like above example. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
tv.setMaxLines(2);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out be setting android:ems="10" it will make your edittext that much wide and wraps the text

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:ellipsize to none for each TextView. For more details see documentation on this attribute.

From xml:

```
<TextView ... android:ellipsize="none" />
```

From code:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
 ...
 textView.setEllipsize(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining your text for the `TextView` in `strings.xml`.Then if you set from html then it may wrap according to screen size:

So you can try this out:

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA[Don&apos;t worry we will never share this with anyone<br/>
By Clicking register you are indicating that you have read and agreed to the <br/>
 <u>Terms of services</u>  and <u>Privacy Policy</u>
]]></string>
```

Then, in your code:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo); foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));
```